# Separate the fields in python

Tags: python, syslog

I have Linux/Unix syslog file and I want to separate the date and the time into variables. How can I achieve it in python?

Here's the log format:

```
Feb 26 14:20:04 laptop kernel: [19.392640] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
```

I want to put `Feb` in a variable and the same goes to the day (26), time (14:20:04), etc.

In shell scripting, I can do it by `cut -d " " -f 1-4` where `" "` is the delimiter and `1-4` is the field number.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just wanting to emulate `cut`, you can split on space and take entries 1-4.

```
>>> logline = 'Feb 26 14:20:04 laptop kernel: [19.392640] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team'
>>> logline.split(' ')[0:4]
['Feb', '26', '14:20:04', 'laptop']
```

(Did you want just the first 3 fields instead?)

You could also use regex, but I don't think it's necessary in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're aiming a bit low.   Python is pretty powerful at this stuff.   Your main problem is that your log file format lacks a year field and lacks a timezone offset field (so it's ambiguous on the day the clocks go back).   Many modern versions of syslog allow you to change the timestamp format, so it's certainly possible to fix that.

```
$ cat log-parse.py 
logdata="Feb 26 14:20:04 laptop kernel: [19.392640] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team"


import re
logrx = re.compile('([^ ]+ [0-9][0-9]? [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9])(.*)$')

m = logrx.match(logdata)
datestr = m.group(1)
fields = m.group(2).split()

print datestr
for i, s in enumerate(fields):
    print "   ", i, s

$ python log-parse.py 
Feb 26 14:20:04
    0 laptop
    1 kernel:
    2 [19.392640]
    3 ip_tables:
    4 (C)
    5 2000-2006
    6 Netfilter
    7 Core
    8 Team
```